# Free software to zoom in/out using curve functions

Tags: software-recommendation, effects, kdenlive, scale, zoom

I need to smoothly zoom "through" a person's eye to another scene behind it. The closest I've come is a linear function zoom in Kdenlive that appears to slow to a crawl the closer you get. I'm guessing I need an exponential function to give the appearance of a constant speed. Ideally you could define or edit a curve controlling the speed at any point. I'd consider getting Premiere Elements if it can do this, but I'd prefer something free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Davinci Resolve has editatable curves for zoom and is free (there is a pid for vesion but the free version has the function). Steep learning curve though, and high high requirement for GPU hardware.

Comment: Thank you so much! The dynamic zoom works perfectly!